# Issue with strip_tags and nl2br

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

im trying to use Strip_tags and nl2br on the content which i echo out from the database. However, strip_tags doesnt work but nl2br does. What i want to do is to remove all the html or php tags inside the content if it is possible. By the way im using php 5.2.17 . Please help.

Output

```
Content:
<p><span style="color: #00ff00;">This is a new Page<br /><br />This is a new sentence</span></p>
```

Content

```
Content:<br />
                            <div class="view-content">

                                <?php echo 
                                strip_tags(htmlentities($current_page["content"])); ?>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `strip_tags` you don't need `htmlentites`. You output is being converted to entites first and so you don't have any tags to strip. Change it to:

```
 <?php echo strip_tags($current_page["content"]); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
echo htmlentities(strip_tags($current_page["content"]));
```

Since you were calling `htmlentities` first, the tags couldn't be recognized in the content because the `<` and `>` characters were replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.